# Read generic collection data from text file

Tags: c#, generics, text, io

I'm using the following method to create save files of generic collection data:

```
public static void WriteDataListToFile<T>(T dataList, string folderPath, string fileName) where T : IEnumerable, ICollection
{
    //Check to see if file already exists
    if(!File.Exists(folderPath + fileName))
    {
        //if not, create it
        File.Create(folderPath + fileName);
    }

    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(folderPath + fileName))
    {
        foreach(var type in dataList)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(type.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I'd now like to create a function to read that data back into an instance of a specified generic collection type, but I'm struggling with how to do this. My current thinking is that the method will have to do the following:

1. split the text file into lines, then split those lines into strings of the individual data types.
2. use reflection to determine the structure of the datatype
3. convert the strings into the types identified in 2 (as per the format of the specified generic collection)

I have the following so far:

```
public static T LoadDataListFromFile<T>(string filePath) where T : IEnumerable, ICollection
{
    //1. Text File to String Representations of Data Types
    char[] splitters = new char[]
    {
        ',', '-'
    };

    List<string[]> dataStrings = new List<string[]>();

    //Check to see if file already exists
    if(File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            //Seperate function I've written to calc num lines in a text file
            int numLines = NumLines(filePath);

            for(int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();

                //remove all of the save formatting from the line(*Possibly do this on save)
                line = line.Replace("[", "");
                line = line.Replace("]", "");
                line = line.Replace(" ", "");

                //split the line as per the specified data splitters
                string[] splitline = line.Split(splitters);

                //add the strings representing different data types from this line
                dataStrings.Add(splitline);
            }               
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //if reading the file doesn't work
        throw new Exception("Cannot load file");
    }

    //2. Determining the datatypes and their structure

    //overall generic type
    Type tType = typeof(T);

    //individual parameter types of generic type
    Type[] tTypes = tType.GetGenericArguments();

    //need to get constructor of types, then instance them, passing the string parameters(converted to their respective types) as parameters for the constructor 

    //for each of those parameter types
    List<object> parameterInstances = new List<object>();

    foreach(Type t in tTypes)
    {
        //create an instance of this particular type, with its parameters
        parameterInstances.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(t, BindingFlags.CreateInstance));
    }

    Debug.Log(parameterInstances[0]);

    //3. Construct the result

    //Create an instance of the overall type and populate it with the results
    var result = Activator.CreateInstance(tType, BindingFlags.CreateInstance);

    return (T)result;
}
```

I'm a bit stuck now, so if anyone can help out, or point me in a direction, that would be appreciated. I know this is a very generic and open request, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: `type.ToString()` will provide the name of the type, not any of the data, unless you've overridden `ToString`.  Look into serializing data rather than just using `ToString`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured serialization might be the way to go. I was looking to do this with text as I like programmatically generating a large generic collection, saving that collection to a text file, altering some of the variables outside of run-time and then I wanted to read that data back into the collection. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Serialize to XML or a custom text format; that will let you play and still deserialize.